# Phonegap - App not installed

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-build

I made a Phonegap app and changed it and rebuilt it a lot of times before, but this is the first time my phone gives me this error:

> App not installed. An existing package by the same name with a
>   conflicting signature is already installed.

I would uninstall the app and try again, but I saved a lot of data using localStorage and I read that uninstalling the app also removes all the localStorage. 
It's weird because this is like the 70th time I update the app...

Comment: Same problems happens with me ... so I just un install and then reinstall it then it work

Comment: "I would uninstall the app and try again, but... I read that uninstalling the app also removes **all the localStorage**."

Comment: Did you upgrade Cordova in the newer version?

Answer (score 0):

This is because something else that is core has changed in the app. This will happen if you switch from using the debug to the release version.

It seems you're trying to install it on Android. You should state this if its correct.

And yes, if you uninstall it you will lose the localStorage data.

Comment: What has changed in your config file? Have you decided to use, or not use, your signing key to generate the apt?

Answer (score 0):

I decided to backup the data and uninstall the app, and then it worked. I hope it doesn't happen again. 
 For the record, I never touched the config file, and this was totally random.